# How set a column as Computed of other column values

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table named tbl_stock and having the columns

```
company_code, Product_ode,Date,Quantity_available, Quantity_recieved,Key_no
```

I inserted all columns except the column `Quantity_available` through a procedure and set the `Quantity_available` as a computed field as

```
modify tbl_stock set st_qty_avl = (st_qty_rsd + st_qty_avl) where (PRODUCT_CODE = PRODUCT_CODE)
```

but its not working

I want the available column as the sum of received + available in every insertion

the available for a product is initialy set as 0

Comment: You need to use UPDATE command rather than modify.

Comment: You have a column `product_ode`? do you mean `code`? You have a column `Date` and you can use it without errors? (Hint: that is not possible, DATE is a reserved keyword in Oracle.)